# Game Center "Error: Failed to find Players"

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, game-center

I'm writing a game for ios7 using the Game Center API and everything works for matchmaking except for when I press "Play Now" on the `GKMatchMakerViewController` and do the random matchmaking. As soon as I press the button, I get the error "Error: Failed to find Players."

I looked up this question and I can't find any answers anywhere-- the other person who was getting this error failed to register his app on iTunes connect but I already did that, and I know setting games up works fine because if I invite a particular person everything works out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have Game Center enabled in iTunes Connect.  It won't actually match you up with anyone until you have everything configured properly on ITC.  It makes you add an icon, a screenshot, and a description in order to actually do it, but if you're early in development just put dummy placeholder items in for those.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already enabled Game Center on iTunes connect. I'm able to play a game if I invite a friend rather than search for a game, so I know matchmaking semi-works.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?  I've been getting it intermittently, but it seemed to correct itself on it's own after a while.

Comment: I got the intermittent problem - I logged out and logged back in again :-) I noticed that I had not enabled Contacts in my GC profile - I did so. It then worked. I wonder if you need to log in again after a big update to iOS.